# GAE giving an error thats not received durning local testing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, telegram-bot

I have this project running on Google App Engine, however when I run the code locally to test it for errors before I deploy it, the log doesn't give any errors and the code works fine.

When i deploy it, GAE gives me a NoneType error. I have a fix for this error but the thing I don't understand is why do I get the error after deployment and not locally ?

logal log:

```
2016-03-21 21:00:34,466 urlfetch_stub.py:540] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host', 'Content-Length']
INFO     2016-03-21 21:00:34,671 module.py:787] default: "GET /testmsg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Success, no errors.

GAE log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/e~thalia-bot/1.391538208721323325/main.py", line 84, in post
textlower = text.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Code :

```
text = message.get('text') #Text that the bot will receive 
textlower = text.lower() #Convert the text to lowercase
```

**Edit:**

After a few redeploys(with different codes) it works fine without changing the original code. The same code that gave me error on GAE works fine now on it. But its not fixed because future deploys will bring up the same issue again. Now I'm even more confused, does anyone spot what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The GAE error doesn't have much to do with the deployment itself, but with `text` (i.e. the result of `message.get('text')`) being `None` or not.

The fact that the same code works after re-deployment could very well be simply an indication of something **else** being changed, for example it could be the request being made.

Try displaying the value of `text` before calling `text.lower()`, you'll likely see it's a different value in the 2 cases - again, nothing to do with the deployment itself.

Comment: I get what your saying, it makes sense, ill give it a shot, thx !